# Take a list of a length query

Tags: javascript

I have a list of query and I would like to print in the console three items of the list.

I tried this:

```
var arrayLength = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr.odd.list-context-actions td.js-file-name.fm-file-name a.i-link.fm-file-name-link span').length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr.odd.list-context-actions td.js-file-name.fm-file-name a.i-link.fm-file-name-link span')[i].innerText;
  //Do something
}
```

How can I keep/print all values of every iteration?

Comment: That just looks like a guess. Do some searching; start with `querySelectorAll` then find something about iterating a collection. Guessing does not count as effort.

Comment: Why don't you add some relevant HTML. You probably don't need a selector that big.

Answer (score 0):

1. Select elements
2. convert to js array
3. slice first three lements
4. map over elements to get inner text

```js
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).slice(0, 3).map(e => e.innerText));

//in long:
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span');
const arr = Array.from(elements);
const firstthree = arr.slice(0, 3);
const innertexts = firstthree.map(e => e.innerText);
console.log(innertexts);
```

```html
<span>a</span>
<span>b</span>
<span>c</span>
<span>d</span>
```